# How do I programmatically disconnect an OpenVPN connection?

Tags: winforms, process, openvpn

I am creating a WinForms application to start and stop an OpenVPN connection on Windows. I am trying to achieve the same functionality as OpenVPN GUI for Windows (http://openvpn.se/) provides but using my own .NET based UI.

I am starting the connection using the following approach:

```
Process openVpnProcess = new Process();
openVpnProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
openVpnProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
openVpnProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--config client.ovpn";
openVpnProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "openvpn.exe";
openVpnProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config";
openVpnProcess.Start();
```

This invokes openvpn.exe and the connection is established successfully.

I am however unable to determine a way to terminate the connection once it is established. I have tried using Process.Kill()

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("openvpn"))
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

This kills the process, but does not restore the initial routing state. Effectively, I cannot access the network until I manually disable/enable my LAN card.

Output of 'openvpn --show-net' before the VPN connection is established:

```
SYSTEM ROUTING TABLE
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.31.0.254 p=0 i=1376258 t=4 pr=3 a=21 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
10.31.0.0 255.255.240.0 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=26 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
10.31.10.235 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=26 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
10.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=26 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=116753 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=26 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=26 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1441796 t=3 pr=2 a=4 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
SYSTEM ADAPTER LIST
TAP-Win32 Adapter V8
  Index = 1441796
  GUID = {013AB57F-DFE6-4FD9-B25E-9589E77DA4EB}
  IP = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
  MAC = 00:ff:01:3a:b5:7f
  GATEWAY =
  DHCP SERV = 172.16.0.0
  DHCP LEASE OBTAINED = Tue Jul 07 16:35:20 2009
  DHCP LEASE EXPIRES  = Wed Jul 07 16:35:20 2010
D-Link DFE-538TX 10/100 Adapter
  Index = 1376258
  GUID = {FB6051A1-E970-4F46-BB85-F442A194BA3D}
  IP = 10.31.10.235/255.255.240.0
  MAC = 00:08:a1:65:70:93
  GATEWAY = 10.31.0.254/0.0.0.0
```

'openvpn --show-net' after VPN connection is closed using Process.Kill():

```
SYSTEM ROUTING TABLE
10.31.0.0 255.255.240.0 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=106 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
10.31.10.235 255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=106 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
10.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=106 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
127.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 127.0.0.1 p=0 i=1 t=3 pr=2 a=116833 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
208.94.64.10 255.255.255.255 10.31.0.254 p=0 i=1376258 t=4 pr=3 a=21 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
224.0.0.0 240.0.0.0 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=106 h=0 m=20/-1/-1/-1/-1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1376258 t=3 pr=2 a=106 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.31.10.235 p=0 i=1441796 t=3 pr=2 a=84 h=0 m=1/-1/-1/-1/-1
SYSTEM ADAPTER LIST
TAP-Win32 Adapter V8
  Index = 1441796
  GUID = {013AB57F-DFE6-4FD9-B25E-9589E77DA4EB}
  IP = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
  MAC = 00:ff:01:3a:b5:7f
  GATEWAY =
  DHCP SERV = 172.16.0.0
  DHCP LEASE OBTAINED = Tue Jul 07 17:02:30 2009
  DHCP LEASE EXPIRES  = Wed Jul 07 17:02:30 2010
D-Link DFE-538TX 10/100 Adapter
  Index = 1376258
  GUID = {FB6051A1-E970-4F46-BB85-F442A194BA3D}
  IP = 10.31.10.235/255.255.240.0
  MAC = 00:08:a1:65:70:93
  GATEWAY =
```

I also tried sending the process `WM_CLOSE / WM_QUIT / WM_ENDMESSAGE` messages but these did not produce any result.

```
const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
const int WM_QUIT = 0x12;
const int WM_ENDSESSION = 0x0016;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam);

foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("openvpn"))
{
    SendMessage(p.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(p.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
    SendMessage(p.Handle.ToInt32(), WM_ENDSESSION, 0, 0);
}
```

---

**Further info on the appropriate solution:** See instructions in section titled *Using the management interface* in [Controlling a running OpenVPN process](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#control).

More info on using [Telnet from C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731105130/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/bigpapa/archive/2007/10/08/C-2.0-and-Telnet---Not-As-Painful-As-It.aspx).

Comment: Related: [C# - Close OpenVPN Cleanly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195210/c-close-openvpn-cleanly)

Comment: I have a similar task now. It seems that's a GUI for openvpn  **server**, meaning you want to control your own opnvpn server. Is that right? If so, why do you pass the argument **-- config client.ovpn** to it?

Comment: you can do it by checking a great project on github that related to openvpn(openvpn-manager). the code in the following link can help you: https://github.com/Searching/openvpn-manager/blob/master/OpenVPNManagerService/OpenVPNService.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this on Windows but you can use the [OpenVPN Management interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html) to send a `SIGTERM` signal with the `signal` command. You'll need to include the management interface configuration entries in your configuration file of course.

More information in the [OpenVPN man page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html)

You may want to look at the way [OpenVPN-admin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-admin/) is doing things. It's working under Windows and Linux and developed with Mono.

Comment: Pierre, your post is a great lead. I'm managed to manually terminate the connection manually using the management interface. 
Further reading: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#control

Answer (score 1):

You're sending messages to the process handle - these, however, are *window* messages, that's why they must be sent to a *window* handle.

**EDIT**
As you got the process already, you might try the following:

```
foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("openvpn"))
{
    p.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

or

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam);

foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("openvpn"))
{
    IntPtr hWnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
    // Send message to hWnd (mind SendMessage's changed signature)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. Can you point me to how I can obtain the Window handle? Would that be using FindWindow()? (I've done very little Win32 programming)

Comment: Edited my answer to give you more info.

Comment: I tried p.CloseMainWindow(); but it does not work. On further research I have realized that OpenVPN Management interface is a more appropriate approach for what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks for more info though, it helped clear a concept.